# Error "no module named six" after a pip install

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Python keeps saying that there's no module named six, however a already used `pip install six`
and reinstalled it several times.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sebastianstoelen/Documents/workspace/Python/kulpno14-15_zilver/PiBot/app/Model/graph.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installation? Are you using the correct `pip`?

Comment: Over the past few days I've installed tons of other libraries using pip, and none of them gave any error. I only have one version of Python (2.7) installed.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a complete beginner in this kind of stuf.

Comment: When all else fails, try rebooting.

Comment: @SebastianStoelen the full traceback is the full error message that you get.

Comment: Can you type `which pip` and `which python` into a bash terminal and post the results?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed my own instance of this problem.
I had two versions of python; the default, 2.6 (which you determine with `which python`), and 2.7.  pip put six under 2.7, but my app ran 2.6, which had only the tar file.

The repair that worked for me:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
sudo cp -rp ../../python2.7/site-packages/six* .
```

My app works as expected now.